# Why did rebooting cause one side of my ZFS mirror to become UNAVAIL?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux, udev

I just recently migrated a bulk data storage pool (ZFS On Linux 0.6.2, Debian Wheezy) from a single-device vdev configuration to a two-way mirror vdev configuration.

The previous pool configuration was:

```
    NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    akita                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Everything was fine after the resilver completed (I initiated a scrub after the resilver completed, just to have the system go over everything once again and make sure it was all good):

```
  pool: akita
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 6h26m with 0 errors on Sat May 17 06:16:06 2014
config:

        NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        akita                      ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

However, after rebooting I got an email notifying me of the fact that the pool was not fine and dandy. I had a look and this is what I saw:

```
   pool: akita
  state: DEGRADED
 status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
         invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
         functioning in a degraded state.
 action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
    see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
   scan: scrub in progress since Sat May 17 14:20:15 2014
     316G scanned out of 1,80T at 77,5M/s, 5h36m to go
     0 repaired, 17,17% done
 config:

         NAME                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
         akita                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
           mirror-0                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
             ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ  ONLINE       0     0     0
             ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA  UNAVAIL      0     0     0

 errors: No known data errors
```

The scrub is expected; there is a cron job setup to initiate a full system scrub on reboot. However, I definitely wasn't expecting the new HDD to fall out of the mirror.

I define aliases that map to the /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-* names, and in case of both these disks have given ZFS free reign to use the full disk, including handling partitioning:

```
# zpool history akita | grep ST4000NM0033
2013-09-12.18:03:06 zpool create -f -o ashift=12 -o autoreplace=off -m none akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ
2014-05-15.15:30:59 zpool attach -o ashift=12 -f akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA
#
```

These are the relevant lines from /etc/zfs/vdev_id.conf (I do notice now that the Z1Z333ZA uses a tab character for separation whereas the Z1Z1A0LQ line uses only spaces, but I honestly don't see how that could be relevant here):

```
alias ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ             /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500645b0fec
alias ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA     /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c50065e8414a
```

When I looked, `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c50065e8414a*` were there as expected, but `/dev/disk/by-vdev/ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA*` were not.

Issuing `sudo udevadm trigger` caused the symlinks to show up in /dev/disk/by-vdev. However, ZFS doesn't seem to just realize that they are there (Z1Z333ZA still shows as `UNAVAIL`). That much I suppose can be expected.

I tried replacing the relevant device, but had no real luck:

```
# zpool replace akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/disk/by-vdev/ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA-part1 is part of active pool 'akita'
#
```

Both disks are detected during the boot process (dmesg log output showing the relevant drives):

```
[    2.936065] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.936137] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    2.937446] ata4.00: ATA-9: ST4000NM0033-9ZM170, SN03, max UDMA/133
[    2.937453] ata4.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    2.938516] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.992080] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    3.104533] ata6.00: ATA-9: ST4000NM0033-9ZM170, SN03, max UDMA/133
[    3.104540] ata6.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.105584] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.105792] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST4000NM0033-9ZM SN03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.121245] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
[    3.121372] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.121379] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.121426] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.122070] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)
[    3.122176] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    3.122183] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.122235] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

Both drives are connected directly to the motherboard; there is no off-board controller involved.

On impulse, I did:

```
# zpool online akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA
```

which appears to have worked; Z1Z333ZA is now at least `ONLINE` and resilvering. At about an hour into the resilver it's scanned 180G and resilvered 24G with 9.77% done, which points to it not doing a full resilver but rather only transferring the dataset delta.

I'm honestly not sure if this issue is related to ZFS On Linux or to udev (it smells a bit like udev, but then why would one drive be detected just fine but not the other), but my question is **how do I make sure the same thing doesn't happen again on the next reboot?**

I'll be happy to provide more data on the setup if necessary; just let me know what's needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a udev issue that seems to be [specific to Debian and Ubuntu variants](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466288/udev-is-creating-wrong-disk-id-symlinks). Most of my ZFS on Linux work is with CentOS/RHEL.

[Similar threads on the ZFS discussion list have mentioned this.](https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!msg/zfs-discuss/sSTbgwerXi4/txQ9EK2yqMMJ)

See:
 [scsi and ata entries for same hard drive under /dev/disk/by-id](https://serverfault.com/questions/535397/scsi-and-ata-entries-for-same-hard-drive-under-dev-disk-by-id/535398#535398)

and
 [ZFS on Linux/Ubuntu: Help importing a zpool after Ubuntu upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, device IDs have changed](https://serverfault.com/questions/565183/zfs-on-linux-ubuntu-help-importing-a-zpool-after-ubuntu-upgrade-from-13-04-to-1/565220#565220)

I'm not sure what the most deterministic pool device approach for Debian/Ubuntu systems is. For RHEL, I prefer to use device WWNs on general pool devices. But other times, the device name/serial is useful, too. But udev *should* be able to keep all of this in check.

```
# zpool status
  pool: vol1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h32m with 0 errors on Sun Feb 16 17:34:42 2014
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        vol1                        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500000e014609480  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500000e0146097d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500000e0146090c0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500000e01460fd60  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: After migrating to bare `wwn-*` names, the pool appears to be stable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling can you detail how you migrated to wwn-* names?

Comment: @codecowboy Nothing fancy at all. `zpool detach akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z333ZA` then `zpool attach -o ashift=12 -f akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ wwn-0x5000c50065e8414a` then `zpool detach akita ST4000NM0033-Z1Z1A0LQ` then `zpool attach akita wwn-0x5000c50065e8414a wwn-0x5000c500645b0fec`, verifying in between each step that the pool was stable. I highly recommend a thorough scrub first. You could probably get away with `zpool replace` as well but since the aliases pointed at the wwn names and I had redundancy plus backups, this felt safer. Took a few days but I wasn't in a rush.