# ZFS Ubuntu - Physically moved drive and no longer recognized by pool

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a 2-drive ZFS mirror pool on Ubuntu.  The drives for the pool were at /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.  For various reasons, I had to physically move the drive at /dev/sda to a different slot in my server, so Ubuntu now recognizes it as being at /dev/sdc.  It seems that, because of this, the zfs pool no longer recognizes that drive and hence marks my pool as degraded.  `zpool status -x` yields

```
  pool: data
  state: DEGRADED
  status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is 
          missing or invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool 
          to continue functioning in a degraded state.
  action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
  see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 12h56m with 0 errors on Sun Apr  9 
        13:20:15 2017
  config:

    NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data                     DEGRADED     0     0     0
      mirror-0               DEGRADED     0     0     0
        9406053825076090209  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sda1
        sdb                  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I tried running some commands I found online involving `zpool replace`, but it seems to complain when I do this because it sees that `/dev/sdc` (`/dev/sdc1`) is a ZFS disk (partition).

Ideally I'd like to just tell ZFS that the missing drive is at `/dev/sdc` -- that should get my pool back to a pristine state.  Another idea might be to tell Linux to swap the labels `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc` -- don't know if that's a crazy idea or not.  Worst case, maybe there is some `zpool replace` command that more or less wipes what's on `/dev/sdc` and rebuilds the mirror on that disk from scratch.  Would really appreciate any advice on what's possible/recommend -- thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to use /dev/disk-by-id/ names instead of RAW SCSI names because something as simple as a USB disk insertion could cause the devices to be renamed.

Please see: [Why did rebooting cause one side of my ZFS mirror to become UNAVAIL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/596712/why-did-rebooting-cause-one-side-of-my-zfs-mirror-to-become-unavail/596721#596721)

You may be able to `zpool export data` followed by `zpool import data`.

---

I'm also concerned there's an `sda1`. You should not have partitions when the other side of the mirror is /dev/sdb.

Comment: Running `zpool export data` then `zpool import data` worked!  Thank you!  Now to find out how to switch from using SCSI names to disk-by-id names...

Comment: You may not have to now. Do a `zpool status -v`

Comment: Now shows `sdb` and `sdc` for the names of the drives in the pool...